# no writeable property 'url' in class 'oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource'

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jta, atomikos

I am writing a JTA transaction management module for the Spring application by `Atomikos`, everything assumed to be properly setup:

```
<bean id="dataSource_JDBC_01" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName"><value>dataSource01</value></property>
    <property name="xaDataSourceClassName"><value>${database_01.xadriver}</value></property>
    <property name="xaProperties">
        <props>
        <prop key="databaseName">${database_01.username}</prop>
        <prop key="user">${database_01.username}</prop>
        <prop key="password">${database_01.password}</prop>
        <prop key="url">${database_01.url}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="poolSize"><value>1</value></property>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource_01" jndi-name="jdbc/DataSource01" default-ref="dataSource_JDBC_01" />
```

Values to those placeholders are quoted from here:

```
database_01.xadriver=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
database_01.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@localhost\:1521\:orcl
database_01.username=USER_01
database_01.password=PASS_01
```

But `Atomikos` throw an exception:

```
no writeable property 'url' in class 'oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource'
2014-12-11 12:00:23,098 -- WARN -- com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException -- Cannot initialize AtomikosDataSourceBean
com.atomikos.beans.PropertyException: no writeable property 'url' in class 
'oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource'
at com.atomikos.beans.PropertyUtils.getSetter(PropertyUtils.java:286)
at com.atomikos.beans.PropertyUtils.setDirectProperty(PropertyUtils.java:200)
at com.atomikos.beans.PropertyUtils.setProperty(PropertyUtils.java:110)
at com.atomikos.beans.PropertyUtils.setProperties(PropertyUtils.java:186)
```

Followed by:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Another resource already exists with name dataSource01 - pick a different name
```

I really cannot tell what is wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it just a matter of capitalize the name of property `URL`. From [Oracle API document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/xa/client/OracleXADataSource.html) class `OracleXADataSource` has a setter method as `setURL()`,  so that the bean name should use

```
<prop key="URL">${database_01.url}</prop>
```

instead of

```
<prop key="url">${database_01.url}</prop>
```

Cheers..